# Upgrade redmine to latest version and move it to latest 20.04. ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, redmine, transfer, migrate

My company have redmine on ubuntu 12.04 and it works fine.
Now we have idea to update it to the latest version of redmine(now its 4.1.1).
We configured new virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04 and have clean install of redmine 4.1.1.
Im interested in easiest way to transfer(migrate) all data and database to new machine(to new version of redmine), so if someone have experience with that I hope you will help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade ? If so, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks for answer but that tutorial is for case if you have one machine and you want to upgrade just redmine there, maybe you did not understand my question..
In my case i have two VIRTUAL MACHINES ubuntu 12.04 (my official redmine with old version)  and ubuntu 20.04(my new virtual machine where i have just clean install of redmine 4.1.1)
Im trying to find way how to transfer all data and files and all database from my official to new system ..

Comment: That is described in the linked guide in Option 1 of Step 3. As for transfering the database, just create a full database dump and load it into your new server with your tool of choice, e.g. `mysqldump`. Then run the rest of the upgrade steps.